# How to automatically fit a callout node, its pointer tip included?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, callout

I'm trying to "automatically" fit a callout node, its pointer included, but I don't manage to include the pointer tip:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, shapes.callouts, fit}
\tikzset{%
    pics/postit/.style n args={3}{code={%
        \node[draw=red,rectangle callout,callout relative pointer={(#1,#2)}] (mynode) {#3};
        \node (pointertip) at ($(mynode)+(#1,#2)$) {};
        \node[draw=green, thick, inner sep=0pt, fit=(mynode)(pointertip)] {};
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {postit={1}{0}{How to}};
    \pic at (0,-1) {postit={-2}{0}{automatically}};
    \pic at (0,-2) {postit={0}{-1}{fit}};
    \pic at (0,-6) {postit={0}{2}{a callout}};
    \pic at (0,-7) {postit={-1}{-1}{node,}};
    \pic at (0,-9.5) {postit={1}{1}{its}};
    \pic at (0,-11) {postit={-1}{1}{pointer tip}};
    \pic at (0,-12) {postit={1}{-1}{included?}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Modify the definition of `\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle` so that it contains the anchor that @percusse mentioned.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you but I think it's too difficult for my level of knowledge. For what I have to do, percusse's answer is already perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer already has an anchor which you can use

```
pics/postit/.style n args={3}{code={%
    \node[draw=red,rectangle callout,callout relative pointer={(#1,#2)}] (mynode) {#3};
    \node[draw=green, thick, inner sep=0pt, fit=(mynode)(mynode.pointer)] {};
}},
```

[image]